# F# Pointless copying after recursive function compilation

Tags: recursion, optimization, f#

I wrote the following function in F# and tried looking at the [decompilation](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFCnIwCuw62AwtgLxXZfafe9eMi2YgEMATkQgB1AJZEAFtgAUEEMKJiZmAOYBKZRHTa1xTTv0dK3a9hlhhAOgAyWbQuwAeNsKPPX7hSx+G2tBbFIRAA92Az8ddwBabABGXWCQgXQhMXQAY2wMMWZ5cVt2dIzrO0cAbRkAXRjDbQc6xsDMCsqQ6pkYiOiOru7KjTp0YZGudGBDSanrQuLSpT74FLSrBe4Zua3tmzARWYnKea4lkrFsAAYefZtd04Wjk6A)

```
let startsWith (s: string) (seg: string) =
    if s.Length <= seg.Length then
        let max = (s.Length - 1)
        let rec perChar i =
            if s.[i] = seg.[i] then
                if i = max then
                    true
                else
                    perChar (i + 1)
            else
                false

        perChar 0 
    else
        false
```

As expected, the inner function is optimised into a while loop however I notice the constant values are assigned to dummy variables and assigned back to themselves in each iteration:

```
    internal static bool perChar@8(string s, string seg, int max, int i)
    {
        while (s[i] == seg[i])
        {
            if (i == max)
            {
                return true;
            }
            string text = s;
            string text2 = seg;
            int num = max;
            i++;
            max = num;
            seg = text2;
            s = text;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I suppose I have a couple questions about this:

1. Why do these dummy names get created?
2. Is there any performance impact or do these pointless copies get optimised out by the JIT before being executed?

EDIT: IL Added

```
    .method assembly static 
        valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Boolean perChar@8 (
            class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String s,
            class [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String seg,
            valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32 max,
            valuetype [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Int32 i
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 40 (0x28)
        .maxstack 8

        // loop start
            IL_0000: ldarg.0
            IL_0001: ldarg.3
            IL_0002: callvirt instance valuetype [netstandard]System.Char [netstandard]System.String::get_Chars(valuetype [netstandard]System.Int32)
            IL_0007: ldarg.1
            IL_0008: ldarg.3
            IL_0009: callvirt instance valuetype [netstandard]System.Char [netstandard]System.String::get_Chars(valuetype [netstandard]System.Int32)
            IL_000e: bne.un.s IL_0026

            IL_0010: ldarg.3
            IL_0011: ldarg.2
            IL_0012: bne.un.s IL_0016

            IL_0014: ldc.i4.1
            IL_0015: ret

            IL_0016: ldarg.0
            IL_0017: ldarg.1
            IL_0018: ldarg.2
            IL_0019: ldarg.3
            IL_001a: ldc.i4.1
            IL_001b: add
            IL_001c: starg.s i
            IL_001e: starg.s max
            IL_0020: starg.s seg
            IL_0022: starg.s s
            IL_0024: br.s IL_0000
        // end loop

        IL_0026: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0027: ret
    } // end of method C::perChar@8
```

Comment: Can you show the IL of the function as well?

Comment: IL Added. As with the C# decompilation, they are copies from sharplab.io. The code looks identical on either Debug or Release. Not sure how to check what compiler version SharpLab is using.

Comment: Indeed. Looks like a codegen bug to me.